# Firebase Google Sign In - Photo URI

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I was able to get the photo URI using this code from the firebase doc

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
        // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
        String providerId = profile.getProviderId();

        // UID specific to the provider
        String uid = profile.getUid();

        // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
        String name = profile.getDisplayName();
        String email = profile.getEmail();
        Uri photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();
    };
}
```

i also have an ImageView called mPic and I tried this code.

```
mPic.setImageURI(null);
mPic.setImageURI(photoUrl);
```

unfortunately, I cannot view the photo. Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Did you print out photoUrl value? Is it http url?

Comment: it is a https url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use picasso library. http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
Picasso.with(context)
           .load(url)
           .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
           .resize(imgWidth, imgHeight)
           .centerCrop()
           .into(image);
```

Comment: i dont understand the parameters context and image

Comment: context is for activity or fragment which you are working on. image is for imageview in your case, it will be mPic.

Comment: last question though, how do i make the image in a circular form?

Comment: No problem. 
Can you try this? Picasso.with(context).load(url).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(image);

Comment: there is an error with CircleTransform(). cannot resolve into a symbol

Comment: Or you can use this library for circle image view. https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Answer (score 1):

```
 Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl())
                        .resize(50, 50)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(yourImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to retrieve the image from "photoUri" to be used in Jetpack Compose.
After countless attempts I found out that the URI actually holds the photo's url, we just need to extract it.
In my app, I extracted the url with this code (**Kotlin**):

```
fun Uri?.getUrl(): String? = this?.run { "https://$host$path" }
```

After getting the URL, you are free to use it in any way.
In my use case, I used it with coil.

```
     AsyncImage(
         model = 
               ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
               .data(url) //Url retrieved from the above function
               .crossfade(true)
               .build(),
         contentDescription = "User image",
     )
```

**Note:** You can also directly use the "photoUri" in data **[*.data(photoUri)*]** as well